# Mysql between time before midnight and after

Tags: mysql, sql

I want this table to return me the between these times in 24h clock. But it returns nothing.

```
SELECT `measurementtime`, 
       `measurementvalue` 
FROM   (SELECT `measurementtime`, 
               `measurementvalue` 
        FROM   `usermeasurements` 
        WHERE  userid = 1 
        ORDER  BY measurementtime DESC 
        LIMIT  30) AS temp1 
WHERE  Hour(measurementtime) >= '16:00:00' 
       AND Hour(measurementtime) <= '04:59:59' 
ORDER  BY Hour(measurementtime)
```

Meanwhile this works perfectly

```
SELECT `measurementtime`, 
       `measurementvalue` 
FROM   (SELECT `measurementtime`, 
               `measurementvalue` 
        FROM   `usermeasurements` 
        WHERE  userid = 1 
        ORDER  BY measurementtime DESC 
        LIMIT  30) AS temp2 
WHERE  ( Hour(measurementtime) BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '11:59:59' ) 
ORDER  BY Hour(measurementtime)
```

So the problem seems to be that I am asking to find times between two different days. So how ? I need to keep these time periods like that and also I don't want to deal with dates.

Entries Are like this

```
        MeasurementTime     MeasurementValue    UserMeasurementID   
    2017-07-11 17:00:00         123                     114 
    2017-07-11 17:00:00         123                     115 
    2017-07-10 20:00:00         12                      116 
    2017-03-15 16:31:00         3                       113 
    2017-03-03 01:03:00         12                      112 
    2016-12-28 15:05:15         39                      109 
    2016-12-19 15:10:29         6                       107
```

(those are not all entries)

Comment: `HOUR` extracts the hour as a number, like `4` or `16`, not as a string.

Comment: Without the date part, you would have to check between midnight and both values. Also, no value will be greater than 16 and less than 4.

Comment: the HOUR extracts the hour and leaves the date from the datetime format

Comment: Exactly. That's the problem. Also, you can't compare "16:00:00" to a number properly.

Comment: @SloanThrasher no integer value but it can be when talking about time, but I also am not sure what you mean? do you say to do time between 16:00:00 AND 23:59:59 AND time Between 00:00:00 amd 04:59:59 ?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the special case of crossing midnight, try this:

```
SELECT `measurementtime`, 
       `measurementvalue` 
FROM   (SELECT `measurementtime`, 
               `measurementvalue` 
        FROM   `usermeasurements` 
        WHERE  userid = 1 
        ORDER  BY measurementtime DESC 
        LIMIT  30) AS temp1 
WHERE  HOUR(measurementtime) >= 16
       OR HOUR(measurementtime) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
ORDER  BY HOUR(measurementtime)
```

If you can do it in a stored procedure with variables, a more general purpose version might be:

```
SET @range_start = 16;
SET @range_end = 4;

SELECT 
    `measurementtime`, 
    `measurementvalue` 
FROM   (SELECT `measurementtime`, 
            `measurementvalue` 
        FROM   `usermeasurements` 
        WHERE  userid = 1 
        ORDER  BY measurementtime DESC 
        LIMIT  30) AS temp1 
WHERE 
    IF(@range_start > @range_end,
        HOUR(measurementtime) >= 16
        OR HOUR(measurementtime) < 4,
        measurementtime BETWEEN @range_start AND @range_end
ORDER BY HOUR(measurementtime)
```

Comment: 1up for the stored procedure, I like it

Comment: If you need to compare to a range that includes minutes and seconds and not just hour, you could use the time() function to get the time part of a datetime. In that case, comparing to "16:00:00" and "04:59:59" would make sense.

Comment: so i should do time(measurementtime) instead of hour(measurementtime)?

Comment: As mentioned, it depends on if your range is specified only in hours, or if it uses hours, minutes and seconds..

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Sloan is good, but here's another option using union

```
SELECT `measurementtime`, 
       `measurementvalue` 
FROM   (SELECT `measurementtime`, 
               `measurementvalue` 
        FROM   `usermeasurements` 
        ORDER  BY measurementtime DESC 
        LIMIT  30) AS temp1 
WHERE  Hour(measurementtime) between '16:00:00' 
       AND '23:59:59' 

union

SELECT `measurementtime`, 
       `measurementvalue` 
FROM   (SELECT `measurementtime`, 
               `measurementvalue` 
        FROM   `usermeasurements` 
        ORDER  BY measurementtime DESC 
        LIMIT  30) AS temp1 
WHERE  Hour(measurementtime) between '0:0:0' 
       AND  '04:59:59'

ORDER  BY Hour(measurementtime)
```

Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b7dad/9/0) to try it out with the data you posted in your question. (I had to remove the userid from the were part to make it work of course.